# Array to object process with underscore library

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, underscore.js

I'm trying to convert javascript objects array to an array of objets of this type {"text" : "value"}, but I have some problems. in other words I want to convert this:

[image]

Into this :

[image]

where "Tag" is my value

How can i do this.

Thanks

Comment: Where does `id` value come from? There is none shown in sample input objects. Is `text` the same as `value` ? Not enough information given.

Comment: Your required output doesn't match your input. Where do you get ALP?

Comment: Please post your snippets as text and format them as code. No pics please.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
data.map(function(d){
  var id = +(d.test.substring(3));
  return {
    value : "ALP",
    id: id 
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need underscore for this. Simple map function from Array.prototype is enough:

```
var myNewArray = myOldArray.map(function(item){
  return {text: item.value};
})
```

For more details on map function visit Mozilla Developer Network site: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map